# infowindow place is incorrect first time

Tags: android, mapbox, infowindow

when i click on marker infowindow appear on incorrect place.
i use onCameraIdle Listener and OnMapClickListener and OnmarkerClickListener.

my layout is rtl.

i think rtl is my problem

```
for(HelperLatLon helperLatLon:list){

                            mapirMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(helperLatLon.getLat(), helperLatLon.getLon())).title("sdfsdfsdf"
                            ));
```

[image]

Comment: Issue resolved. if layout was rtl first time that click on marker ,infowindow appear  in incorrect place but next time is correct. but if layout wasn't rtl infowindow appear in correct place

Comment: Great you found a solution! Do you mind adding your answer so it's discoverable?